# How to pass an NSMutableString which is instantiated in an accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath method to another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need a way to pass the variable "resultStringID" to the second view "DetailViewController" from "RootViewController" every time the user clicks the accessory button. Here is my code for the accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



processSelected = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//realstatusSelected = [processStatusarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//NSLog(@"Real selected status is %@", realstatusSelected);
NSLog(@"combinedString at index is %@", processSelected);


NSMutableString * resultStringID = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:processSelected.length];

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:processSelected];  
//define the allowed characters, here only all numbers are allowed 
NSCharacterSet *allowedChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890"]; 

while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {  
    NSString *buffer;  
    if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:allowedChars intoString:&buffer]) {  
        [resultStringID appendString:buffer];       
    } else {  
        [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];  
    }  
}  

//Trim off the last 3 characters if the string is larger than 4 characters long
if ( [resultStringID length] > 4 )
    resultStringID = [resultStringID substringToIndex:[resultStringID length] - 3];
```

Any help is very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add an `@property (copy) NSString *myString` to your DetailViewController, then when you create the new controller (just before pushing it) set `newController.myString = resultStringID`.

Comment: Thanks alot! That was a simple and elegant solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to present/push this DetailViewController? The typical way, would be create your own init method for DetailViewController

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andResultId:(NSMutableString*)resultStringID
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        // Do stuff with your resultStringID
    }
    return self;
}
```

And then push it like always:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] andResultID:resultStringID];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

I assumed that you wanted to push it. If, on the contrary, the DetailViewController already exists, and you have a reference to it, just add another @property (nonatomic,retain) for your string.